# Ubuntu Touch availability on Windows tablet

Tags: windows, ubuntu-touch, acer, tablet

Can I install Ubuntu Touch on an Acer W510 tablet? I couldn't find any instructions at ubuntu.com.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you were able to install ubuntu? I want to do the same thing but I don't get any results when I google "installing ubuntu acer w510"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a possibility by using a bootable USB drive.

You can make your USB drive bootable so that you can use it to install Ubuntu from that USB. You can do this using **unetbootin** for instructions on how to do the [Unetbootin site](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) will have the information you'd need....

Comment: Thanks for marking my post as useful.....

it's good to see it helped you

Comment: What about Ubuntu Touch distributive? Where i can get it?